# git clone - permissions OK when run from Windows command line but not from Cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, git, permissions, cygwin

If I run a 'git clone' from the Windows 10 command line to a Linux remote repo in our office, there seem to be no permission issues; I'm presented with an ssh login prompt to the remote server, my password is accepted, and the clone runs to completion without a problem.

If I run the same 'git clone' from Cygwin, I don't even get the login prompt and the git command fails with:

Permission denied (publickey,password)

The thing is, I think I know why the problem is happening, but not what to do about it.

Image my name is John Smith. My credentials as stored by the remote Linux server are 'john.smith'. My Windows user folder is 'C:\Users\john.smith'. However, when I start a Cygwin session, the prompt is actually 'John.Smith@myhostname'. So because Windows is case-insensitive, the git clone works because the Windows copy of 'known-hosts' can be located (no case issues). However, the copy of 'known-hosts' in Cygwin isn't being located because of the mismatch between the Unix username (john.smith) and the Cygwin username (John.Smith). That's my theory anyway !

What do I need to do in Cygwin to lower-case my username so that everything aligns ?

Thanks

Comment: See [change default username when ssh to another pc](https://superuser.com/q/306152/173513) and [How to make ssh log in as the right user?](https://superuser.com/q/64996/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to issue the clone command with the format: `john.smith@linuxhost:path/to/repo`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried the clone both with & without my explicit username; Cygwin throws the permissions error with both formats.

Comment: This is a long shot, but you can try to create a new user in cygwin: `/bin/mkpasswd -d -u john.smith >> /etc/passwd`, and change user `su - john.smith` ang git clone again...

Answer (score 0):

Check  where your git configuration is
    git config --list --show-origin
cygwin probably uses /home/john.smith as home/profile folder(directory).

But here is main issue ssh configuration.
You could copy your ssh private and host keys from windows location to cygwin home .ssh directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Cygwin install folder under `<install-path>/Cygwin/home/<username>`

You should find:

- **.gitconfig** - edit this to change your username and email address etc...
- **.ssh** - this contains your known-hosts and id_rsa ssh keys. You probably need to copy your windows ones into here.

You may also find other issues in Cygwin like auto complete not working? and a few other gotchas...?